# Questions regarding a Java Queue implementation from CTCI

Tags: java, queue

I am looking at the implementation of Queue from Cracking the Code Interview 5th Edition.

The explanation of enqueue is as follows:

```
class Queue {
    Node first, last;

    void enqueue(Object item) {
        // This indicates the Queue is empty
        // so we set both first and last as 
        // the same item
        if(first == null) {
            last = new Node(item);
            first = last;
        } else {
            last.next = new Node(item);
            last = last.next;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand what is going on in the if-statement. This conditional deals with an empty queue. So if the queue is empty, and we're trying to add an item to the queue, the item added is both the first and last item.

However, what I am not understanding is what's going on in the else statement. The book first assigns the item as the `last.next`, and then assigns `last` as `last.next`. Wouldn't this make both the last and last's next element the same thing? Also, I illustrated the queue. Is this an accurate illustration of the positions of `last` and `last.next`?

```
[      |      |      |      ]

    ^     ^
  last  last.next
```

Comment: Well, yes.  It is creating a new node, adding it to the end of the list, and setting the last reference to point to that new, last node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the else section:

```
1: last.next = new Node(item);
2: last = last.next;
```

Here's the LL we start with:

```
(a) -> (b) -> (c)
 ^first        ^last
```

We call enqueue(d)

After line 1 runs:

```
(a) -> (b) -> (c) -> (d)
 ^first        ^last
```

So we see that line 1 creates a new element at the end of the list, but `last` still points to `(c)`.

After line 2 runs:

```
(a) -> (b) -> (c) -> (d)
 ^first               ^last
```

Now, `last` points at `(d)` which appropriately has no `next` node.

You see, `(c)` never goes away, it is simply the `last` *reference* that is *moved*.

As for *why* this is how it works, it all comes down to the fact that objects are references in Java.

Consider this code:

```
Object x = 300;
Object y = 500;
Object z = x;

//here, x = 300, y = 500, z = 300

x = y;
//now, x = 500, y = 500, z = 300
//because the actual object that x initially pointed to was not changed, only x as a reference was changed.
```

In the case where the list has size `n=0`, and `n=1` respectively:

```
NULL
^first,last

NULL    (a)
^first   ^last

(a)
 ^first,last
```

Then another call

```
(a)
 ^first,last
(a)     ->     (b)
 ^first,last

(a)     ->     (b)
 ^first         ^last
```

Hope that helps

Comment: In your example, is `first.next` on the left or right of `first`, and is `last.next` on the left or right of `last`?

Comment: The arrows indicate the `next` element of the node.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you so much.

Comment: in tangent to this topic, would you represent it in the same way you did here: `(a) -> (b) -> (c) -> (d)` where `(d)` is the top?, and `(c)` is `top.next`?

Comment: I personally prefer to show arrows in these types of diagrams as going from the object that contains a reference to the object it's referencing, but that's just my personal preference. For a stack, I'd probably write `(a) <- (b) <- (c)` with `top = c` and `top.next = b`

Comment: Hi Collin. I have another question. If in the event that there's only one node in the Queue, such that `first` == `last`, it seems `first.next` is never assigned to last if we perform `enqueue()` using the CTCI solution. Is this right or wrong?

Comment: In the event that enqueue is called on a list with size n = 1, `first == last` and so `last.next` being assigned also assigns `first.next`.

Comment: is this because of the pass-by-reference thing? Also.. `last.next` is the new node being entered, while `first.next` will need to be `last` - how does assigning `last.next` also assigning `first.next` know the right node to assign as next?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the specific cases of `n={1,2}`

Comment: Oh thank you. I think what I got confused in is my incorrect assumption that Queues need to care what `first.next` and/or `last.next` is much like a LinkedList traversal. I forgot that Queues only care about what the `first` and `last` is.

Comment: In this case, `first.next` is critically important to the functionality of the queue.